# How to get all columns in Spark DataFrame recursively

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I want to get all columns of DataFrame. If DataFrame has a flat structure (no nested StructTypes) `df.columns` produces correct result. I want to return all nested column names also, e. g.

Given

```
val schema = StructType(
  StructField("name", StringType) ::
  StructField("nameSecond", StringType) ::
  StructField("nameDouble", StringType) ::
  StructField("someStruct", StructType(
    StructField("insideS", StringType)::
    StructField("insideD", DoubleType)::
    Nil
  )) ::
  Nil
)
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row]
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

I want to get

```
Seq("name", "nameSecond", "nameDouble", "someStruct", "insideS", "insideD")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this recursive function to traverse the schema:

```
def flattenSchema(schema: StructType): Seq[String] = {
  schema.fields.flatMap {
    case StructField(name, inner: StructType, _, _) => Seq(name) ++ flattenSchema(inner)
    case StructField(name, _, _, _) => Seq(name)
  }
}

println(flattenSchema(schema)) 
// prints: ArraySeq(name, nameSecond, nameDouble, someStruct, insideS, insideD)
```

Comment: This generates only for one level, Can you share it if we have schema which has Arrays as values and they again have struct type in them?

Comment: Without testing this again - it seems like it should handle any number of levels, thanks to recursion. Did you test it and it doesn't?